# Magento - blank homepage and "Fatal error: ../app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43" in admin

Tags: magento

My Magento site has suddenly stopped working. The homepage loads a blank page, and when I go to the admin I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object in ../app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43
```

I have deleted the cache and session files but this didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Var folder has proper permission.

When captcha image are created they first get store in var folder.
Due to improper permission images will not be saved.This will result in a NULL  object hence that error.

Comment: Turns out this was the issue. Not sure what caused the Var folder permission to change in the first place, but resetting it to 0777 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your store doesn't use captcha, then rename the folder `./app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/` to something other like `./app/code/core/Mage/Captcha_old/` then you can access the site.

Comment: worked for me. not sure what was the cause for this…